# UWP mediaplayerelement how to display extra text on top part of transport media control?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am writing a UWP 14393 app using mediaplayerelement in xaml file, I am wondering how can I display extra information in text on top of custom transport media control so that when player control is up, the text will show up at the same time?

For example, for a video player showing an online stream, and at the top left corner shows streamer name, view count, etc. The information only shows up when player control shows up.

Obviously, the best way to do this is to put the text inside custom transport media control, is it doable? If not, how can I achieve this?

I am a newbie at UWP, so any help will be welcome, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can custom the `MediaTransportControls`'s style, and add your own content to `<Border x:Name="ControlPanel_ControlPanelVisibilityStates_Border">`. See my test.

[image]

First download `MediaTransportControls`'s style from [my gist](https://gist.github.com/hupo376787/cf6f40c7dc2cc91f5e5b30625c8d38ab).
Or you can find it in your pc's `generic.xaml` file.

Then add this style to `App.xaml`.

```
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="/MediaTransportControls.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
```

Then you can use your style in `MediaTransportControls`.

```
<MediaPlayerElement
    Width="300" Height="500"
    AreTransportControlsEnabled="True"
    Source="ms-appx:///Assets/elephantsdream-clip-h264_sd-aac_eng-aac_spa-aac_eng_commentary-srt_eng-srt_por-srt_swe.mkv">
    <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
        <MediaTransportControls Style="{StaticResource myMediaTransportControlsStyle}">

        </MediaTransportControls>
    </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
</MediaPlayerElement>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<MediaPlayerElement AreTransportControlsEnabled="True">
    <MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
        <MediaTransportControls>
        <Grid>
            <...Put any content here like textblocks and buttons all this content will be part of controls so they will appear and disappear along with the controls, this Grid covers all the area on the screen ( above the controls bar )...>
        </Grid>
        </MediaTransportControls>
    </MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls>
</MediaPlayerElement>
```

Comment: I accepted this as answer just thinking it totally makes sense, without really testing it out. I finally get around to test it today, and get the error of "The type MediaTransportControls does not support direct content", what is wrong?